# Tips when testing a connected Redux Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-redux, enzyme

I've pasted my Component below which is very, very basic. When the Component is mounted, it will basically call the `fetchMessage` Action, which returns a message from an API. That message will in turn get set as `state.feature.message` in the `mapStateToProps` function.

I'm at a complete loss on where to begin testing this Component. I know that I want to test that:

1) The Feature Component is rendered

2) The `fetchMessage` function in `props` is called

3) It displays or has the correct `message` property when rendered using that

I've tried setting my test file up as you can see below, but I just end up with repeated error after error with everything that I try.

Could anyone point me in the right direction with what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

class Feature extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fetchMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMessage();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.feature.message };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

Test file:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import Feature from '../index';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

describe('<Feature />', () => {
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      feature: {
        message: 'This is the message'
      }
    });
  });

  it('renders a <Feature /> component and calls fetchMessage', () => {
    const props = {
      fetchMessage: sinon.spy()
    };

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Feature {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('Feature').length).toEqual(1);
    expect(props.fetchMessage.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Testing Connected React Components**

Use separate exports for the connected and unconnected versions of the components.

***Export the unconnected component as a named export and the connected as a default export.***

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

// export the unwrapped component as a named export
export class Feature extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fetchMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMessage();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.feature.message };
}

// export the wrapped component as a default export
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

Remember *connected components must be wrapped in a Provider component* as shown below.

Whereas unconnected components can be tested in isolation as they do not need to know about the Redux store.

*Test file:*

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';

// import both the wrapped and unwrapped versions of the component
import ConnectedFeature, { feature as UnconnectedFeature } from '../index';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

describe('<Feature />', () => {
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      feature: {
        message: 'This is the message'
      }
    });
  });

  it('renders a <Feature /> component and calls fetchMessage', () => {
    const props = {
      fetchMessage: sinon.spy()
    };

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <connectedFeature {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('Feature').length).toEqual(1);
    expect(props.fetchMessage.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this work - you didn't explicitly export `UnconnectedFeature` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shallow()` instead of `mount()` to test your component. The `shallow()` method calls the `componentWillMount()` life-cycle method so there is no reason to use `mount()`. (**Disclaimer:** I am not quite well at `mount()` yet.)

For connected components, you can pass a store object like this:

```
<connectedFeature {...props} store={store} />
```

And you should call `shallow()` method twice to make it work for connected components:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<connectedFeature {...props} store={store} />).shallow()
```